# bash script.sh vs ./script.sh vs #shebang

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, centos

Assuming i am in a bash shell now and i execute the following

```
[me@server]$ bash script.sh
```

q1) Is a new child bash process created to execute the script ?

If i do a

```
[me@server]$ ./script.sh
```

q2) Is a new child bash process created to execute the script ?

q3) What is the difference between the 2 methods then ?

Comment: http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-script.php

Answer (score 1):

From [Dot slash explanation](http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html)

The difference you do is,

with `sh`, you're running a program that will `interpret the lines in your script` just as it you would have typed them on the interactive prompt of the terminal,

with ./ you're making a shortcut assuming that the script is just right here in the current directory you're sitting in AND it will be executable (because for instance you issued chmod +x myscript.sh),

Additional info from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136550/64188) answer :

> For your specific script either way will work, except that ./script.sh
>   requires execution and readable bits, while bash script.sh only
>   requires readable bit.
>
> The reason of the permissions requirement difference lies in how the
>   program that interprets your script is loaded:
>
> ./script.sh makes your shell run the file as if it was a regular
>   executable. The shell forks itself and uses a system call (e.g.
>   execve) to make the operating system execute the file in the forked
>   process. The operating system will check the file's permissions (hence
>   the execution bit needs to be set) and forward the request to the
>   program loader, which looks at the file and determines how to execute
>   it. In Linux compiled executables start with an ELF magic number,
>   while scripts start with a #! (hashbang). A hashbang header means that
>   the file is a script and needs to be interpreted by the program that
>   is specified after the hashbang. This allows a script itself to tell
>   the system how to interpret the script.
>
> With your script, the program loader will execute /bin/bash and pass
>   ./script.sh as the command-line argument.
>
> bash script.sh makes your shell run bash and pass script.sh as the
>   command-line argument So the operating system will load bash (not even
>   looking at script.sh, because it's just a command-line argument). The
>   created bash process will then interpret the script.sh because it's
>   passed as the command-line argument. Because script.sh is only read by
>   bash as a regular file, the execution bit is not required.

Answer (score 0):

1. a child bash process is create
2. same as above (due to shebang)
3. the two are equivalent, if you do not want to fork a child, or want to keep env value from `script.sh`, use

   ```
   . ./script.sh
   ```

beware however

- if `script.sh` call exit, you will exit current shell.
- if shell end with no error you are return to initial shell.

Comment: `. script` is the same as `source script` - see `help source` (at bash prompt) for more.